# Java проверить примитивный ли тип

Tags: java, типы

Как проверить в Java примитив у нас или обьект?...
..Задание вообще из книги, Вот такое : "Напишите программу, которая определяет, является ли массив char примитивным типом или "настоящим" обектом.

Comment: Именно массив, а не его элементы? Массив вроде по определению и так самый настоящий объект.

Comment: ну меня бы устроило и сам элемент. Хатя по заданию именно массив, думаю мне важно понять принцип того как это выяснить.

Comment: я щас прохожу тему про тип Class и примитив както в коде можно проверить его при помощи char.class и Character.TYPE но как немогу понять

Comment: Но массив проверять бессмысленно!!! Он является объектом по определению!!! Можно проверить является ли он массивом примитивов или же объектов. Поучить тип элементов `array.getClass().getComponentType()`. Проверить на примитивизм `array.getClass().getComponentType().isPrimitive()`. Проверить тип `array.getClass().getComponentType() == char.class` или `array.getClass().getComponentType() == Character.TYPE`

Comment: Незнаю как тут лайкать, Sergey спасибо! Я наверное понял почему именно массив по заданию. Потому что нельзя получить(наверное) тип класс из примитива.

Comment: Про рефлексию почиайте

Comment: @Sergey оформите нормальным ответом

Comment: @Kompot [что делать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), когда ответ помог вам решить проблему (в вашем случае, когда появится какой-то ответ) - так мы "лайкаем". Кроме того, вы можете кликнуть на стрелочку вверх, слева от комментария, если навести туда мышку, но это ни на что не влияет, кроме отметки, что вы согласны\одобряете этот комментарий.

Comment: @pavlofff Комментарий - не ответ. Кто может развёрнуто написать (а там есть что разворачивать), тот пусть и отвечает.

Comment: @Sergey, ваш комментарий вполне годится как ответ. Если вы его запостите, то получите плюс к репе, а сайт улучшит статистику по проценту отвеченных вопросов)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте расставим точки над i.
Формулировка

> является ли массив char примитивным типом или "настоящим" обектом.

является некорректной, так как массив в Java - самый обычный объект, унаследованный от Object.

Тогда ответим на вопрос -

> как определить, являются ли элементы данного массива объектами или
> примитивными типами?

Давайте проведём исследование и выполним простой код

```
 String[] strArr = {"one", "two"};
 int[] intArr = {1, 2};
 System.out.println(strArr);
 System.out.println(intArr);
```

Мы получим следующий вывод:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@6d06d69c                                                                                                                                                                       
[I@7852e922
```

Массивы в Java, в отличие от коллекций, не умеют просто так распечатывать свои элементы в методе toString(), но имя класса массива может сообщить нам кое-что полезное. Мы можем видеть, что для массива объектов типа String вывод начинается с **[Ljava.lang.String**, а для примитивных int - с **[I**. (Дефолтный вывод объекта без переопределения *toString()* - *имякласса@хэш*)
Если залезть в документацию то можно увидеть, что первые символы в строковом представлении массива соответствуют следующим типам:

- [Z = boolean
- [B = byte
- [S = short
- [I = int
- [J = long
- [F = float
- [D = double
- [C = char
- [L = any non-primitives(Object)

(этот список я скопировал с [этого поста](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085889/l-array-notation-where-does-it-come-from))

И это - первый способ узнать является ли данный массив массивом примитивов или нет: посмотреть с чего начинается имя класса массива.

```
myArray.getClass().getName()
```

Второй - **правильный способ** - был предложен в комментарии к посту пользователем
@Sergey.

```
myArray.getClass().getComponentType().isPrimitive()
```

Метод *getComponentType()* возвратит объект типа *Class*, соответствующий классу элементов массива, если был вызван для объекта типа *Class* самого массива, в противном случае - null. (сложное получилось предложение. Но, как пример неправильного использования: *"Hello".getClass().getComponentType()* вернёт null)
У объекта типа *Class* есть метод *isPrimitive()*, назначения которого, мне кажется, понятно из названия - проверка является ли соответствующий ему элемент примитивным.